# Types of a,b,c when you see "from a.b import c" in a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When I see

```
from a.b import c
```

in a python script, can I safely assume that

- a.py is a python script on the module search path
- b is a class in a
- c is a method in b

? I made these assumption because [the official document on python modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) says this:

> There is a variant of the import statement that imports names from a
> module directly into the importing module’s symbol table. For example:
>
> > > > from fibo import fib, fib2
> > > > fib(500) 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377

So, according to this document, the thing after "from", namely, fibo above, should be a module, right? (first assumption above)

Comment: No, you can't - you can't import just a single method out of a class. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: The import system is written up in the language reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from a.b import c
```

For simplicity, here `a` is the package (it is basically a folder, though it has some special attributes), `b.py` is the file name under the package `a` and `c` is either a class or a function defiled in `b.py`.
Also, here `a` may be a package, `b` is a sub-package and c.py may be the file name. If that is the case, then if there is a function my_function in c.py, you need to use c.my_function in your program.

For more details look into https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: `b` may as well be a sub-packages (folder).